# PHP Login with and Multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array, authentication

Im pretty new to PHP so please forgive if i'm missing some of the basics.

What i am trying to achieve here is logging in by comparing an ID of a HTML
input area in a PHP script.

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="PHP/Processes/LoginPage.php" method="POST">
    <input placeholder="User Name" type="text" id="Username" name="Username"/>
    <input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" id="Email" name="Email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is where i'm storing my "users" :

```
<?php

$users = [
'Calum' => [
    'Email' =>'user101@gmail.com',
    'userPassword'=>'PaswordCalum',
    'userDOB'=> '15.10.1976',
    'userFirstname'=> 'Calum',
    'userName'=>'User101'
],

'Calvin' => [
    'Email' =>'User202@gmail.com',
    'userPassword'=>'PasswordCalvin',
    'userDOB'=> '15.10.1976',
    'userFirstname'=> 'Calvin',
    'userName'=>'User202'
],

'Louise' => [
    'Email' =>'User303@gmail.com',
    'userPassword'=>'PasswordLouise',
    'userDOB'=> '15.10.1976',
    'userFirstname'=> 'Louise',
    'userName'=>'User303'
]
];
```

Okays so here is my PHP file so far:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php

 include '../LoginFiles/userCredentials.php';

 if($_POST['Username'] === $users['userName'])
 {
 echo "Logged in";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Still not workingg";
 var_dump($users);
 ;}

 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

You are probably asking why i would want to do it this way and not use a database, well i'm trying to learn it this way first and then move onto a database, i'm really just taking baby steps to try and learn php in general, so any help or pointers would be a great help and i thank you in advance!

Comment: I immediately noticed an error, two ' ; ' , remove the last.
This is correct :
 var_dump($users); }

Comment: Don't directly run into array then, try single user login system. In which only one user is present. And then move to database. Eventually you need to go to database. Try to learn database tools first and then  Implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check username is an inner element of the multi-dimensional array.

So, you need to get all usernames in an array and check posted username in it.

```
$usernames = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $usernames[] = $user['userName'];
}
```

Now, check username is this new array.

```
if (in_array($_POST['Username'], $usernames) {
  echo "Logged in";
}
else {
  echo "Still not workingg";
  var_dump($users);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this website, explained easy way
basics of php http://www.w3schools.com/php/  ,
basics mysql for db maintainance
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$ username = $_GET ['Username']    $ user = $ users [$username]    If ($ user == null){
// user not existent
} else {
// validate password

}
```

Sorry I'm typing this from mobile device